# registering to RhoConnect push notifications using Ionic, phonegap or cordova

Tags: cordova, push-notification, motorola

does anybody know if there is an already existing plugin which enables registering to RhoConnect push notifications using Ionic, phonegap or cordova?

[RhoConnect Push Client Setup at Zebra technologies](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.4/rhoconnect/push-client-setup)

Answer (score 1):

No there is not an exisiting plug-in for this provided by Zebra. You will have to write one yourself.

We are also intending to Open Source the entire platform. Please see the [FAQ's for more details](https://developer.zebra.com/community/rhomobile-suite/rhomobile-community/rhomobile-blogs/blog/2016/03/30/rhomobile-open-source-faq).

Comment: you're `Rob Gavin` which appears as one of the Authors in the Zebra help page you link to, Right?